# Network UDP logger with replay

Tags: windows, logging, udp

I need network logger utility with ability to replay the data it collected, for example, I will record incoming data on UDP port 1234 for 10 minutes, record it to file, then replay that data (with same timing) to some other address:port.

It has to run on windows, and it can be standalone process that will listen to UDP port exclusively, so it doesn't have to be 'sniffer'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I created my own tool for that.  If there is interest, I'll post it for everyone to use.

The mere utility is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10020780/releases/UdpCapturerApplication.exe), sources to be available soon.

Comment: Daniel,
I would be interested in that.

Comment: @ClaytonDukes I'll post it to sourceforge and let you know.  Thanks for the interest.

Comment: I would suggest not posting an answer until you are ready to post the tool. Answers such as these are not useful until you have content in them.

Comment: @Adrian you are right, the tool is linked in the answer text!

Answer (score 2):

The best option I know of is [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/).  Bit-Twist will replay packet captures and runs on Windows.  I don't know anything that works as a stand-alone process, listens on a UDP port, and then allows you to replay that with proper timing, though.  I've never seen or heard of anything that operates in that way (live forwarding, yes, store and forward, no).

Comment: well, it says: With Bit-Twist, you can now regenerate your captured traffic onto a live network! Packets are generated from tcpdump trace file (.pcap file). Bit-Twist also comes with a comprehensive trace file editor to allow you to change the contents of a trace file.

Comment: Yeah.  It should do what you're looking for, working from traffic capture, sniffer style.  It won't however, be a "standalone process that will listen to UDP port exclusively".